# Вызов конструктора из конструктора с

Tags: java, конструктор

не понимаю почему так нельзя сделать

```
public class xxx {

public xxx (boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d){  
}

public xxx (int i){
    switch (i){
        case 0:
            this(false, false, false, false);
            break;
        case 1:
            this(false, false, false, true);
            break;
        case 2:
            this(false, false, true, false);
            break;
   }
}
```

могу ли я использовать swith в конструкторе + вызов конструктора из него?

Answer (score 2):

this(...) должна идти первой строкой в конструкторе.

можно сделать static функцию для получения нужного объекта:

```
public class xxx {
    public xxx(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d) {
    }

    static public xxx getByCase(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new xxx(false, false, false, false);
            case 1:
                return new xxx(false, false, false, true);
            case 2:
                return new xxx(false, false, true, false);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

//где-то в коде
int foo = getSomeValue();
xxx bar = xxx.getByCase(foo);
```